# svn checkout repo with files containing ? in their filenames on windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, svn

I recently joined a team that uses svn, and most of the team members use ubuntu.

I also use ubuntu 50:50 with windows, but some team members strictly want to use windows.

They keep getting error e720123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

This is fixed if we remove the files from the repo that contain question marks in their filenames - but this isn't a permanent fix as these files need to be in the repo.

Is there any way we can tell svn to checkout the repo except for those files (there is only one aspx? file per branch)

"Just remove the files with question marks from the repo" - that isn't a solution, I don't have the political ability to do this. I am looking for a workaround.

If anyone knows how I can checkout a branch except for one file, I would appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: i have a bad idea, install a ssh server on windows, and checkout within  it's terminal client.

Comment: what you tried out?

Comment: Honestly, IMHO, if the requirement is to have filenames with question marks, then the problem isn't the requirement, it's the people dictating the requirements!!

Answer (score 1):

Huh, Just decorate your URI within two `"`:

```
explorer "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=...."
```

for more info see those:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files
2. http://thepursuitofalife.com/escape-characters-in-windows-cmdexe/
3. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true